# How to place a button on the TopLevel window in tkinter python?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, toplevel

**Answer as pointed out down for other innocent newbies like me**
in python2, we have Tkinter
In python3, we have tkinter.

Notice the difference in casing. Thats the reason, why error was coming up.

I have two screens: window(child) and root(master)
I am trying to place a button on the "window" screen created by the method: command(). I have written this piece of code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def writeText():
    print "hello"
def command():
    window=Toplevel(root)
    Button(window,text="Button2",command=writeText).grid()
    Label(window,text="hello").grid()

button = Button(root, text="New Window", command=command)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

But this button2 is not appearing on the second screen. Meanwhile, Label is appearing on this screen. And the control is going into the writeText() function.

And when I remove the command argument from the Button of window screen, the button appears.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: So, you have two screens, "root" and "window". You want "window" to pop up when you press "button". When the "window" pops up it should have "Button2" and "hello" on it. Am I right?

Comment: Yes Eshita, you grasped the right meaning. Though, now I have modified the question a little. So please read it again to understand the problem that i am facing.

Comment: So, with the command = "writeText" for the "Button2" on "window", the "Button2" does not show up anywhere. But, without the command, it does show up?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what is happening

Comment: i think because you are not passing arguments to `grid` both the label and the button are being put in the same place, as such the label (added later) hides the button behind it. try adding `row` and/or `column` arguments to put them in different places.

Comment: @JamesKent: if you call `grid` with no arguments, it will _not_ place objects in the same place.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The button with `Button2` as a label shows up in the new window. Are you claiming _this exact code_ doesn't show the button on the popup window?

Comment: Your code works fine for me as well however it appears you are using python 3+ from your imports but your print statement looks like it is from python 2. Maybe if you correct you import to be `Tkinter` instead of `tkinter` it might fix the problem?

Comment: @SMT, good point, i didn't notice tkinter import. That might be the reason. I will let you know if that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

From your question you have put `from tkinter import *` however in your tags you put `Python 2.7`. This is contradictory because `tkinter`(all lower case) is used in Python 3.x and `Tkinter` should instead be used for python 2.x. That said try fixing your import first. If you are in fact using Python 3 then you will need to correct your print statement to include brackets. `print("hello")`

2nd I would try to follow PEP8 more closely however in this case I don't see anything out of the ordinary that would cause this issue.

Take my below example and let me know if you are still having the same problem.

Python 2.x example:

```
import Tkinter as tk # Upper case T in Tkinter for Python 2.x


root = tk.Tk()

def write_text():
    print "hello"

def command():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Button(window,text="Button2",command=write_text).grid()
    tk.Label(window,text="hello").grid()

button = tk.Button(root, text="New Window", command=command)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Python 3.x example:

```
import tkinter as tk # all lowercase tkinter for Python 3.x


root = tk.Tk()

def write_text():
    print("hello") # Python 3.x requires brackets for print statements.

def command():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Button(window,text="Button2",command=write_text).grid()
    tk.Label(window,text="hello").grid()

button = tk.Button(root, text="New Window", command=command)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

If you are still having problems can you tell me if you are using Windows, Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Have you guys ever tried button with image on Toplevel? It seems it cannot be work with code below on Toplevel(Prompt out windows). Root level is ok.

```
tp = Toplevel()
tp.geometry("400x400")

btnphotoAdd=PhotoImage(file="32adduser.png")
btnAdd = Button(tp, text="Add User", font="Helvetica 20 bold", image=btnphotoAdd,compound=TOP)
btnAdd.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: its a good question.
but it would be better if you ask it in a separate thread.